# Novel: Magic is derived from the bodies of dead gods

Tags: story-identification, novel

I walked into the store, leafed about 100 pages in, and all I remember is a scroll was made out of pieces of a sacrificed minor deity, literally, she had been slaughtered and used as a spell ingredient. I was distracted and did not buy the book. Googling only gets me garbage about Egyptian *'Book of the Dead'*...

I am almost 100% that it was a full-length book.

Comment: This novel mentions "heroes pillaging magic from the bodies of dead gods"; https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/36419544-tales-from-the-void

Comment: Actually sounds a little like S. John Ross's RPG supplement, *Uresia: Grave of Heaven*.

Comment: This description reminds me a little of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Broken_Kingdoms.

Comment: Not a perfect match, but it might have been [Three Parts Dead](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13539191-three-parts-dead) or one of the other novels from the Craft Sequence.

Answer (score 6):

Could this be the short story ***The Heart of Nefarious*** by Chris Fox (from the [Tales of the Void](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/36419544-tales-from-the-void) anthology)

> Aran accepted the mirror and held it up to his face. His stubble threatened to become a beard, but at least it aged him up a little. He was two years shy of his quarter century, which marked full adulthood on Virkon. Most societies considered humans to be an adult at sixteen or eighteen. **Of course, most societies weren’t founded around stealing magic from dead gods to extend their life.**
>   His skin tingled as Aran stepped through the pillars, and a low subsonic hum quickened for a moment. Whatever magic it employed passed almost instantly, and he stepped through with no trouble.

Later there's mention of a "dripping scroll" which is implied to have been dipped into the blood of a god to sanctify it.

Answer (score -1):

*The Godless* (*Children trilogy*, book 1, 2014) by Ben Peek.

From [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LB89TJS):

> Fifteen thousand years after the War of the Gods and their corpses now lie scattered across the world, slowly dying as men and women awake with strange powers that are derived from their bodies. While some see these powers as a gift - most call them a curse.
>
> When Ayae - a young cartographer's apprentice in the city of Mireea - is trapped in a burning building, she is terrified as a dormant power comes to life within her. The flames destroy everything around her but she remains unscathed - fire cannot touch her. This curse makes her a target for the army marching on her home - an army determined to reclaim the body of the god Ger, who lies dying beneath the city, and harness his power for themselves.
>
> Zaifyr, a man adorned in ancient charms, also arrives in Mireea. His arrival draws the attention of two of the 'children of the gods', Fo and Bau, powerful, centuries-old beings who consider themselves immortal. All three will offer different visions for Ayae's powers - and whatever choice she makes will result in new enemies.
>
> Meanwhile, as the army approaches ever closer to Mireea, the saboteur Bueralan and Dark, his mercenary group, look to infiltrate and learn its weaknesses. Alone in a humid, dangerous land, they find themselves witness to rites so appalling they realize it would take the Gods themselves to halt the enemy's attack - and even they may not be enough.

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is a good match to the question asked?